# didBeginContact not working properly

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I created a struct PhysicsCatagory for each of the different objects I want interacting with each other

```
struct PhysicsCatagory {
    static let Blade : UInt32 = 1
    static let Laser : UInt32 = 2
```

}

above my class GameScene

```
 class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {
```

and I initialized an SKSpriteNode blade with its physicsBody in the didMoveToView method

```
override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self
    Blade.position = CGPointMake(self.size.width / 2, (self.size.height / 14))
    Blade.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, -0.13)
    Blade.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: Blade.size)
    Blade.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCatagory.Blade
    Blade.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCatagory.Laser
    Blade.physicsBody?.dynamic = false

    self.addChild(Blade)
}
```

As well as a SKSpriteNode laser and its physicsbody in the method shootLaser

```
func shootLaser(){
    var Laser = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Laser.png")
    Laser.position = Enemy.position
    Laser.zPosition = -5
    Laser.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: Laser.size)
    Laser.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCatagory.Laser
    Laser.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCatagory.Blade
    Laser.physicsBody?.dynamic = false

    let action = SKAction.moveBy(laserVector, duration: 0.7)
    let actionDone = SKAction.removeFromParent()
    Laser.runAction(SKAction.sequence([action,actionDone]))
    self.addChild(Laser)
}
```

But when they collide in the simulation, the didBeginContact method is not called and "Hello" is not printed

```
func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
NSLog("Hello")
}
```

Why isn't the didBeginContact method being called when they collide? Thanks in advance (:

Comment: Maybe you forgot <SKPhysicsContactDelegate>?

Comment: It could be that your category and contact bit mask are set to optionals. change the ? to ! in both the contact and category bit mask

Comment: I actually did include SKPhysicsContactDelegate. I wasn't clear about that. Also making the category and contactBitMask not optionals didn't seem to work either ):

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sprite Kit does not check for contacts between non-dynamic physics bodies because they aren't expected to move. If you don't want your sprites to fall off the screen due to gravity, set the physics body's `affectedByGravity` property to `false` and set `dynamic = true`.